# Python Quickstart: WARNING:oauth2client.util:__init__() takes at most 4 positional arguments (5 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get started with the python quickstart for the google drive api, so I downloaded the necessary python libraries and copied and pasted the quickstart.py into a local python directory.

When I try to run the the file it gives the error "WARNING:oauth2client.util:**init**() takes at most 4 positional arguments (5 given)" (when I add import logging). And the link that it provides asks for you to authenticate (like it should) but when you click yes, it automatically redirects you to the specified redirect uri (instead of giving the verification code).

Not sure whats wrong, seeing as I didn't personally code anything just got everything from the website here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python

Comment: The code samples are often out of date wrt the libraries, which get updated without release notes of breaking changes.

Comment: Also that link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the code to be returned the redirect URI must be the specific value `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. The warning is unrelated to your problem. To eliminate the warning, update this line:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
```

to:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE,
                           redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
```

I've made this change to the quickstart as well.